# Insignificant input variable but high R2

Tags: r, regression, python, linear-model

I was doing linear regression in R and Python and I got this doubt.

Can a linear regression model with a single input variable `x` with `x` not significant but the model has a high $R^2$?

Can this exist? If yes, what are the reasons?

```
fit <- lm(y ~ x1, data=test1)
summary(fit)
```

Comment: Can you add your example code?

Comment: The results of `summary(fit)` would be very helpful. That would tell us how many observations and so forth. If there's only 1 predictor and 1 dependent variable, a plot would be great, too.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you mean with **"x not significant"** that the slope of your linear regression is not significantly different from 0.
Additionally, the statement "the model has a high $R^2$ is not very precise. Above which threshold is $R^2$ "high"?

Nevertheless: If you have a very low sample size (e.g. only 3 observations) then it may happen that the confidence interval for the slope is so large that it still includes 0 although the linear relationship seems to be obvious.

Comment: If your problem occurs with a large sample size, it would be more worth investigating.